# search for the debut chess book

Tags: opening, books, 1.d4, uncbv

I have been playing chess for a long time, I think every chess player who was more or less eager to comprehend the vastness of this game and reach new heights has a challenge - there is no single main opening, I myself play, unorthodox or incorrect openings, which is why I often remain in a bad position and often lose.

I decided to fix problems with debuts ( openings ), I took up the study of theory rigorously, my rating began to rise and grew by about 100 points .

The second problem I faced was not understanding the basic ideas of the opening, which I painstakingly studied to advance up the rating ladder in attempting to comprehend the vastness of : **1. d4**  and realizing that it would be difficult for myself and perhaps even futile - I decided to study books on opening theory where basic ideas are explained.

I found a series of books by the author Boris Avrukh (who had previously  written 3 books on the opening in which I am interested). I wanted this book in cbv format making for speed and quality- I found the 3rd volume on the Internet.

After reading it, I realized that the author of the book really deserves all kinds of awards for it, but only the side lines for the d4 move are covered in my volume 3 , and  I realized that to continue learning, two Volumes   (Volume  1 & Volume 2 ) would be needed.

**Where can I locate the first two parts of  Boris Avrukh's d4 opening theory repertoire (preferably in Russian)?**

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: I suppose by "debut" you mean "opening"?